# How much would you pay to play this game?

Tags: probability, expected-value

There is a game in which you have a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of winning 100 dollars and getting the fee you paid to play the game back. There is a $\frac{2}{3}$ of losing the fee you payed to play the game. How much would you pay to play this game?

My approach:

$\frac{1}{3}(100+x)+\frac{2}{3}(-x)=x$

Solving this equation we get $x=25$

This means that, on average, we break even if we pay $25$ dollars.

So, I should be willing to pay any amount under $25$ dollars to play this game.

Is this the correct thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The house (whoever runs this game) puts 100 in the pot (that usually means on the table between you). You pay the buy-in of $x$, which is to say, you put $x$ in the pot. Then you play.

I see two ways of thinking about this:

$\frac{1}{3}(100)+\frac{2}{3}(-x)$ is the expected net change in your wallet contents after playing the game one time (including the action of paying the buy-in). For a fair game, you want that to be $0$.

$\frac{1}{3}(100+x)+\frac{2}{3}(0)$ is how much money you're expected to take from the pot after playing the game one time. For a fair game, you want that to be equal to the buy-in $x$.

Either approach works, but mixing them like you did gives the wrong result.

Your analysis after the equation solving is correct, though. Any buy-in below what gives a fair game will tilt the game in your favour.